# How to get values in two different div inside a php loop

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I am trying to get a loop like this. Suppose i have 20 rows in table `test` and i need to get its id values inside a loop like below.

```
 <section class="test">
       <div class="n4">

         <div class="n2">
              1 // first row id
         </div>

        <div class="n21">
            2 // second row id
        </div>

    </div>
    </section>

    <section class="test">
       <div class="n4">

         <div class="n2">
              3 // third row id
         </div>

        <div class="n21">
            4 // fourth row id
        </div>

    </div>
    </section> 

      ..... <section> ....upto all ids in the row
```

What i am tried to do is
Suppose table test has 20 rows.

```
    <?php
    $query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM test");  
    $counter=1;
    foreach($query as $row)
    {
    ?>
    <section class="test">
       <div class="n4">

       <?php  if($counter %2 !=0)  ?>     
         <div class="n2">
            <?php echo $row['id']; ?> 
         </div>
         <?php else  ?>
        <div class="n21">
            <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
        </div>

    </div>
    </section>

     <?php
  $counter++;

  } ?>
```

This is not showing the exact result.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way will work as you want, i have try this as well

```
<?php
$query = [['id' => 1], ['id' => 2], ['id' => 3]] ; // example of result
for ($i=0; $i < count($query); $i+=2) { 
    try {
        ?>
    <section class="test">
        <div class="n4">
            <div class="n2">
                <?php echo @$query[$i]['id'] // ignore error ?>
            </div>
            <div class="n21">
                <?php echo @$query[$i+1]['id'] // ignore error ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
        <?php
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}
```

Above will produce result like this

```
<section class="test">
    <div class="n4">
        <div class="n2">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="n21">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="test">
    <div class="n4">
        <div class="n2">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="n21">

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Did you missed foreach($query as $row) ?

Comment: Because error showing as `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in `

Comment: i'm sorry about a mistake, because i try that with array formatted query result as example

Comment: Yes...seems to working, but how i add my query ids to this array

Comment: You can use `$result = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);` to convert sql result as array

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong with your code, lets try this

```
<?php
$query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM test");
$counter=1;
foreach($query as $row)
{
    ?>
    <section class="test">
    <div class="n4">

    <?php  if($counter %2 !=0): /* you've missing ":" symbol*/ ?>   
        <div class="n2">
        <?php echo $row['id']; ?> 
        </div>
    <?php else: /* you've missing ":" symbol*/ ?>
        <div class="n21">
        <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; /* you dont need close bracket, but you need "endif" */ ?> 
    <?php $counter++; ?>
    </div>
    </section>

<?php  } ?>
```

Comment: This code show same as i tried way .. this will produce like this https://jpst.it/1bmbg,